# What was the classic term for "damnatio memoriae"?

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, example-request, reference-request

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damnatio_memoriae) on the subject notes that the term *damnatio memoriae*, referring to the relegation of a person's name to oblivion, as if they never existed, is a neo-Latin expression first attested in 1689.

What wording do the ancient sources use when speaking about the practice? While the [German Wikipedia article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damnatio_memoriae) refers to the term *abolitio nominis*, I seem to be unable to find any direct references to it either.

Comment: Possible lead for a Post-classical alternative: I think in the Old Testament the name of Moses is commanded to be erased from Egiptian history by the Pharaoh, but I don't know if it is elaborated as a properly named concept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Russian and polish wikipedia say the classical term was *memoria damnata*, or *abolitio memoriae*, without, however giving a direct source. Goettingen's Institute of Archealogy uses *memoria damnata* in a short [article](http://viamus.uni-goettingen.de/fr/e/uni/d/03/05) on the concept
2. Adrastos Omissi, [Emperors and Usurpers in the Later Roman Empire: Civil War, Panegyric, and the Construction of Legitimacy](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=CWliDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA36&dq=Damnatio%20memoriae%201689&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwis6Yn6nP3xAhWkyosBHRGFB-wQ6AEwAnoECAYQAg#v=onepage&q=Damnatio%20memoriae%201689&f=false), Oxford University Press, 28 june 2018, page 36, ISBN 978-0-19-255827-5 says

> On near-equivalent terms used by Roman writers, see F. Vittinghoff,
> Der Staatsfeind in der römischen Kaiserzeit: Untersuchungen zur
> 'damnatio memoriae', Neue deutsche Forschungen, Abteilung alte
> Geschichte 2, Berlin, Junker und Dünnhaupt, 1936, pages 64-74

3. This monography [Der Staatsfeind in der römischen Kaiserzeit: Untersuchungen zur 'damnatio memoriae'](https://www.deutsche-digitale-bibliothek.de/item/SBSEMMREJFBD5C4RGX2MGQ52RQV72OFJ) exists. Unfortunately, I couldn't find an available copy
4. Yet, the [Martelage et damnatio memoriae : une introduction](https://www.persee.fr/doc/ccgg_1016-9008_2003_num_14_1_1590), Stéphane Benoist, Cahiers du Centre Gustave Glotz, Année 2003, 14, pp. 231-240, mentions, and quotes! the german monography: [image]

"oder genauer der memoria damnata" - "or, more precisely, the memoria damnata"

Note, at this point, the relevant [comment](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/6040/what-was-the-classic-term-for-damnatio-memoriae/18095#comment38033_18095):
*Please note that Vittinghoff rejects "memoria damnata" just like "damnatio memoriae" as erroneus and says Roman historians either talked about individual sanctions or talked about the decision to condemn the name or image in general. –
Sebastian Koppehel
Apr 17 at 18:34*

5. In [Mutilation and Transformation, damnatio memoriae and roman imperial portraiture](https://books.google.pl/books?id=5IpPhTqnDJkC&pg=PA2&lpg=PA2&dq=memoria%20damnata&source=bl&ots=rGo34pP5n3&sig=ACfU3U25MnObdf1jsOkJUOGJDgtu8Bs8mg&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiU_7TWupv3AhUUuosKHVgrASsQ6AF6BAgEEAM#v=onepage&q=memoria%20damnata&f=false), Eric R. Varner, 2004, Brill, page 2, one can read

> When discussing the condamnation of a person's memory and monuments,
> ancient authors usually combine the word *memoria* with particulary
> strong verbs *damnare, condemnare, accusare, abolere,* or *eradere*

with the following footnote:

[image]

*Memoria damnata* seems to be recurrent.

Comment: Please note that Vittinghoff rejects "memoria damnata" just like "damnatio memoriae" as erroneus and says Roman historians either talked about individual sanctions or talked about the decision to condemn the name or image in general.

Comment: Thanks much pápilió for the excellent summary! I see a lot of paper digging coming my way! :-) Would you mind incorporating the Sebastian's note into to the answer? The comments are fleeting, and his seems to add a very useful bit of information. As part of your welcome to SO, a tidbit: If you want to link to a comment, it is the comment's _date_  ("N hours/days ago" or a real date after a few days) that is a hyperlink to it. This isn't intuitive and hard to find at first.